# OpenCV: No GPU support (The library is compiled without CUDA support)

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

I installed opencv 2.4.6.1 with cmake and with option WITH_CUDA=ON.
I tryed some samples code and it worked well.
But some trouble lies with gpu library.
I add in the source file:

```
cv::gpu::printShortCudaDeviceInfo(cv::gpu::getDevice());
```

And it returned: 
`OpenCV Error: No GPU support (The library is compiled without CUDA support) in getDevice, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.2+dfsg/modules/core/src/gpumat.cpp, line 182 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception' what(): /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.2+dfsg/modules/core/src/gpumat.cpp:182: error: (-216) The library is compiled without CUDA support in function getDevice`

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have a mix of two different versions of OpenCV on your system (2.4.6.1 and 2.4.2).  The older version (2.4.2) appears to be built without GPU support.

You might try removing any older versions of OpenCV *completely* and start your build process for 2.4.6.1 over again.

Comment: Thank you. In fact i didn't install cuda.